# vshost32.exe Error While Debugging

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

Everytime i try to debug in VS2013 i get "vshost32.exe has stopped working error."
I tried  debugging it on x86 cpu only and changing the settings to disable visual studio hosting process or to allow unsafe code in project settings (solutions I've seen while searching online),yet I keep getting the same error and I can not debug,however the program compiles correctly,if I go to the debug folder and run the exe independently it works.The only change I get is;if I turn the visual studio hosting process to off,I dont get the vshost error but i get "myprogram.exe" has stopped working error.Does anybody have a solution for this,because i'm about to get nuts here :(
Oh and the same thing also happens in VS2012...

Comment: Did you try different solutions? What code are you executing on the start? Could you try to run an empty Windows Forms project and see if it runs?

Comment: I always try with a blank winforms project...

Comment: Okay, well you said you used the `x86` CPU? Have you tried the `Any CPU` option? This could also be a firewall/antivirus issue.

Comment: Yeah I have tried all of the options there. :(

Comment: Have you looked into your firewall/antivirus?

Comment: Firewall is off,I have uninstalled my antivirus.Most likely its system related.Looks like I'm gonna reforamt this,or try it on a different system...

Comment: OMG I had same problem ... but can't remember how did I solve it. What antivirus did you have?

Comment: I think I got that problem after removing av (probably Kaspersky). As far I can remember the AV had updated a shell command in registry for devenv.exe. That means each time devenv.exe is requested, the dll AV's DLL loads first. After removing AV the DLL remained in AV install folder. Also av had not revert shell command in registry back to its initial state. The result was: the DLL would loads first but it was unable to do its job due to missing antivirus components. I've solved the problem by reverting registry shell command to its initial state. Hope you got my point (my English). Good luck!

Comment: Cheers all,after fiddling (a lot) I think i have find a solution to this;after unticking "prefer 32 bit" in project setting,it seems to work be working miraculously... :/

Comment: Thanks @Sin5k4! That workaround fixed it for me too, which suggests it may be related to debugging 32-bit processes only. This started happening out of the blue for me yesterday.